# How to resolve a neo4j authentication error?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I am a beginner on Neo4j. I had a version Neo4J 2.23 and I migrated to 3.2.14 on a Linux 2.6.18-398.el5 x86_64, which is a remote server.

I configured the Neo4j.conf file to my server's IP address, port, and everything else.

I run: `./neo4j start`

the user password: set "neo4j" which is the default password, this is the first connection specified in the attachment neo4j_1.

and then I encounter this error as shown in the attachments

**Screenshot 1**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Screenshot 3**

[image: screenshot 3]

**Screenshot 4**

[image: screenshot 4]

Comment: I am beginner on neo4j.

I had a version neo4J 2.23 and I migrated to 3.2.14 on a Linux 2.6.18-398.el5 x86_64, which is a remote server.

I configured the neo4j.conf file according to the IP address of my server, the port and everything that follows.

I run: ./neo4j start

it asks for the password of the user: I put "neo4j" which is the password by default, since it is the first connection indicated in the attachment neo4j_1. and then I encounter this error as shown in the attachment

Comment: Please edit the question and replace the French with the English text.

Comment: it's done, the question is edited in English

Comment: Maybe the title as well?

Comment: Don't see any attachment with the error. Also, the attachment in not in English can you share the error message in English?

Comment: the error: 
A problem has occurred: " NotFoundError:Unable to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': the node to delete is not a child of this node.
"And the application can not recover.

Comment: Hello,
I solved the problem that I mentioned above,
by adding these two parameters in the file neo4j.conf
dbms.allow_format_migration = true
(since I'm upgrading from version 2.2 to version 3.2)
and the bolt connector
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address = 0.0.0.0: 7687
it escaped me at the beginning
Thank you